# CMake: Can't find git for clone of FetchContent dependency

Tags: git, cmake, github-actions

I'm using FetchContent to get the targets of another github cmake project. Locally everything builds fine, but in my github workflow, I'm getting this cmake error: `"error: could not find git for clone of ppcdisasm-populate"` (full logs here https://github.com/em-eight/aipg/actions/runs/4036584360/jobs/6939279457)

My CMakeLists (https://github.com/em-eight/aipg/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt) is seemingly very simple and I'm even maually setting GIT_EXECUTABLE. `which git` returns /usr/bin/git as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the logs, I observed that `HorstBaerbel/action-ctest` is using a container i.e. https://github.com/em-eight/aipg/actions/runs/4036584360/jobs/6939279457#step:5:7 and https://github.com/HorstBaerbel/action-ctest/blob/master/Dockerfile#L1. And, it looks like that container doesn't include `git`. See https://github.com/HorstBaerbel/ccpp-cmake-build-and-test/blob/main/Dockerfile. So, you need to [create an issue](https://github.com/HorstBaerbel/ccpp-cmake-build-and-test/issues/new/choose) there and get it included to make this work. Also, https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23102.

Comment: Ah, thanks! After some tests it seems GIT_EXECUTABLE is not being set inside his container. I became short-sighted after verifying that git was available in mine

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe, the presence of `git` wasn't expected inside the container itself. But, as the CMake configuration may use plugins that use other executables to accomplish their functionality, there should be some control or configurable method to apply by which such external deps may be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your logs, it has been observed that [HorstBaerbel/action-ctest](https://github.com/HorstBaerbel/action-ctest) is using a container i.e. check your logs for the `docker run` command; and, see https://github.com/HorstBaerbel/action-ctest/blob/master/Dockerfile#L1.

That container itself doesn't include `git`. See https://github.com/HorstBaerbel/ccpp-cmake-build-and-test/blob/main/Dockerfile.

So, you need to [create an issue](https://github.com/HorstBaerbel/ccpp-cmake-build-and-test/issues/new/choose) there and get it included to make this work.

Here's a relevant issue from the CMake repo: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23102